# Word for 'items not in a set'

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for 'items not in a set'?

Here is the desired usage: when I organize things into boxes by source (could be brand, author, sender... any logical way to group items) I have a box for source X, a box for source Y, etc. I can use X, Y as the labels for the boxes. Now all the rest goes into a box, what should I label it with?

In my mother tongue there is a word for that, literally 'scattered' in English. I don't believe 'scattered' is the right word here.

In English, the closest word I could think of is 'miscellaneous', which may work for the label of the box, but the meaning isn't the same as what I want. Other options include 'ungrouped' and 'uncategorized', which aren't exactly true because the items in that box are indeed categorized. They are categorized as 'not in a collection'.

What is the right word?

Comment: *Miscellaneous* sounds perfectly fine to me. Can you elaborate as to why you don't think it's the word you're looking for?

Comment: @WendiKidd Maybe my understanding is wrong but 'miscellaneous' makes me feel the items do not serve major purposes instead of are coming from diverse sources.

Comment: *Miscellaneous* is fine, or just *misc* for short.  So are *ungrouped* and *uncategorized*.  You could also label the box *other*.

Comment: *Miscellaneous* does not imply triviality; it signifies a *mixture*, a diversity of categories. If your organizing principle is "SOURCE", then the label *miscellaneous* signifies that the box labeled contains works from many sources, not just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a single word, you could consider **uncategorized**. One [dictionary](http://www.wordnik.com/words/uncategorized) defines it as:

> **uncategorized** (*adj*.) not having been sorted into a category

Or, if you don't mind a short phrase, you could try **odds and ends**. This phrase gets its own entry in several [dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=odds%20and%20ends&ls=a) – [one](http://www.wordnik.com/words/odds%20and%20ends) of them defines it as:

> **odds and ends** (*n. pl.*) that which is left; remnants; fragments; refuse; scraps; miscellaneous articles.

If you don't like *odds and ends*, that definition has an assortment of other candidates you could use, such as *remnants*.

I'll suggest one more word: **other**. That can work as a category name, and has even been used in some applications.

<sub>Examples of usages of an "other" category can be found [**here**](http://www.otago.ac.nz/healthsciences/students/professional/otago034664.html), [**here**](http://watsonville.patch.com/groups/valerie-lemkes-blog/p/have-you-checked-your-other-mail-folder-on-facebook) and [**here**](http://support.klout.com/customer/portal/articles/1122329-what-does-the-%E2%80%9Cother%E2%80%9D-category-represent-within-my-network-recommendations-graphs-).</sub>